# Access-Control-Allow-Origin not working for image extensions in Nginx

Tags: nginx, cross-domain

I have this configuration in nginx to add cross-origin and **its working fine**, the header Allow-Origin is present in response headers:

```
location ~* \.(woff|woff2|oft|eot|ttf)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=1604800";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
        log_not_found off;
}
```

but when I try to do exactly the same for image extensions its not working, no Allow-Origin header in response headers:

```
location \.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|flv|pdf|thumb)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=29030400";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
        log_not_found off;
}
```

Why is not working for images?

Comment: The problem is that the server is not accesing through images location for any reason...I put a custom header in both cases and only the "fonts" location return that header... but I don't know why....

Answer (score 0):

I was using a regular expression "." without a regular expression prefix like "~" or "~*".